# Find the values of 'a' in a $4\times 4$ matrix(A) when the determinant is less than 2012

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The matrix is $A \ =\begin{pmatrix}
                    7 & 1 & 3 & -2\\
                   -2 & 1 & -12 & -1 \\
                    1 & 16 & -4 & a \\
                    2 & 4 & 2 & 2 \\
                   \end{pmatrix}$

Where $\det(A)\lt  2012$

I have tried reducing the first columns to 0's to reduce it to a $3\times3$ determinant. When I do that it gets messy fast. Is there a special method to solve this problem?

Comment: If that gets messy, just try expanding along a row or column. You'll get four 3 by 3 determinants, not that bad.

Comment: Using determinant rules and dividing the last row through by 2 might make the algebra a little less messy

Answer (score 3):

$A \ =\begin{pmatrix}
                    7 & 1 & 3 & -2\\
                   -2 & 1 & -12 & -1 \\
                    1 & 16 & -4 & a \\
                    2 & 4 & 2 & 2 \\
                   \end{pmatrix}\cong \begin{pmatrix}
                    13 & 1 & 5 & -5\\
                   -5 & 1 & -25 & -3 \\
                    -14 & 16 & -24 & 2a-16 \\
                  0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
                   \end{pmatrix}$

S0, you would get $\det(A)=-4\det\begin{pmatrix}
                    13 & 5 & -5\\
                   -5 & -25 & -3 \\
                    -14  & -24 & 2a-16 \\
                  \end{pmatrix}$

Can you finish this and fill the gaps?

Comment: What are your row operations?
Why is it -4? I thought it would positive 4 because column 4+row 2 = an even number

Comment: I have done column operations and not row operations... I did something and ended up with last row with three zeros... There may be some computational errors but this is one of the easy ways... -4 came because i am considering minors/cofactors corresponding to 4,2th element...

Comment: yes yes it is +4.... It is column 2 row 4

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is any special trick, but you can kill off the $(1,4)$-th and $(4,4)$-th elements of $A$ easily using the second row. This leaves you two $3\times3$ determinants to compute, if you Laplace-expand $\det A$ along the last column.

Comment: Dear user1551, left a comment at an answer of yours from March 2013. Please take a look, I was surprised to find that there is a published algorithm (a Schaum's outline) for solving $P^T A P = D,$ where $A$ is symmetric and $P$ is invertible but not orthogonal. Standard topic in quadratic forms over $\mathbb Q$ (my thing) not well known otherwise to students, and questions on the topic are often confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this matrix and make the determinant less tedious by performing row operations and introducing some zeros:

1. $R_4 \rightarrow R_1 + R_4  $
2. $ R_1 \rightarrow R_1 -2R_2$

The above two operations gives the following matrix:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
11 & -1 & 27 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & -12 & -1\\
1 & 16 & -4 & a\\
9 & 5 & 5 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

3. Expand along column 4:

$$ -1 \det\begin{bmatrix}
11 & -1 & 27\\
1 & 16 & -4\\
9 & 5 & 5
\end{bmatrix} - a \det\begin{bmatrix}
11 & -1 & 27\\
-2 & 1 & -12\\
9 & 5 & 5
\end{bmatrix} $$

After computing, you get the following:

$$2612-300a < 2012$$

$$  a > 2$$

when $a = 2$, $\det A = 2012$